# jQuery/JS - Intercept URL change for navigation without hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, navigation

I'm working on some new navigation and I wanted to get rid of the hash in the onhashchange navigation. Similar to how Google does it on services like photos.google.com. The URL explicitly changes when you navigate around (even when going backwards) but the page does not reload. It acts like a hashchange but isn't actually using a hash. Any idea on how to do this?

Thanks,